# "Error wrapping InputStream in GZIPInputStream" while running Play project

Tags: java, exception, playframework, sbt

I was working on my Play project when I got BSOD. After computer rebooted I started getting the following exception when trying to run any activator command (like `activator clean` or `activator run`):

```
[info] Done updating.
Error wrapping InputStream in GZIPInputStream: java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.translate(ErrorHandling.scala:10)
    at sbt.WrapUsing.open(Using.scala:34)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:23)
    at sbt.IO$$anonfun$gzipFileIn$1.apply(IO.scala:863)
    at sbt.IO$$anonfun$gzipFileIn$1.apply(IO.scala:862)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
    at sbt.IO$.gzipFileIn(IO.scala:862)
    at sbt.Sync$.readUncaught(Sync.scala:88)
    at sbt.Sync$.readInfo(Sync.scala:84)
    at sbt.Sync$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Sync.scala:28)
    at sbt.Sync$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Sync.scala:22)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$copyResourcesTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:941)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$copyResourcesTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:937)
    at scala.Function4$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function4.scala:35)
    at scala.Function4$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function4.scala:34)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:165)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:79)
    at sbt.Using$$anonfun$gzipInputStream$1.apply(Using.scala:84)
    at sbt.Using$$anonfun$gzipInputStream$1.apply(Using.scala:84)
    at sbt.Using$$anon$1.openImpl(Using.scala:51)
    at sbt.WrapUsing$$anonfun$open$2.apply(Using.scala:34)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.translate(ErrorHandling.scala:10)
    at sbt.WrapUsing.open(Using.scala:34)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:23)
    at sbt.IO$$anonfun$gzipFileIn$1.apply(IO.scala:863)
    at sbt.IO$$anonfun$gzipFileIn$1.apply(IO.scala:862)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
    at sbt.IO$.gzipFileIn(IO.scala:862)
    at sbt.Sync$.readUncaught(Sync.scala:88)
    at sbt.Sync$.readInfo(Sync.scala:84)
    at sbt.Sync$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Sync.scala:28)
    at sbt.Sync$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Sync.scala:22)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$copyResourcesTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:941)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$copyResourcesTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:937)
    at scala.Function4$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function4.scala:35)
    at scala.Function4$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function4.scala:34)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (root/compile:copyResources) Error wrapping InputStream in GZIPInputStream: java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
```

I tried all workarounds I managed to find. I deleted the "project" and all "target" folders in the project I tried to run and the project it depends on. I deleted ".sbt" folder in "C:\Users...". I even cleaned TEMP directory. Nothing helped - I still get this error after "Loading project definition from.." and "Resolving..." messages in the log. What else can be done to solve the issue?

Comment: No, I do not work with ZIP files in my project. And according to https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3050 this exception is not about zip files, but an sbt issue.

Comment: I even tried to clone my projects from master repository in git to another folders and this did not help either.

Comment: What happens if you don't use activator (which is now end of lifed) and just use vanilla sbt instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem - there were some other dependent projects, when I cleaned them the issue disapppeared.

Answer (score 6):

Try to clean the project's target directory

```
cd ${your_project}
rm -fr project/target
rm -fr project/project/target
```